# Table trigger doesnt run and default values dont be taken, if updated/inserted by .NET MySqlDataAdapter

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview, mysql-python

I am using a MySql DB, having a trigger (modifed timestamp afterupdate) at table 'tbl_person'. This trigger works fine, eg. using MS ACCESS as frontend. But if I use a DatagridView VB.NET, which is using a bindingsource to MySqlAdpater, then the update method of the adapater is running in a way, that neither the trigger runs nor the default values are used.

I wonder what is the reason for this, how to prevent this and are there better ways to use a datagridview in combination with MySQl ? Perhaps someone can give me some hints.

If you want to try this: The code can be easily copied, only connection and table name must be changed.

This code origins from MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/fbk67b6z(v=vs.110).aspx

```vb
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class Form2
Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

Private dataGridView1 As New DataGridView()
Private bindingSource1 As New BindingSource()
Private dataAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter()
Private WithEvents reloadButton As New Button()
Private WithEvents submitButton As New Button()

Private connectionString As String = _
"server=127.0.0.1;user id=adm_test2;password=12init34;database=MyDb"

Private strSelect As String = "SELECT * FROM tbl_Person"

<STAThreadAttribute()> _
Public Shared Sub Main()
    Application.Run(New Form2())
End Sub

//' Initialize the form.
Public Sub New()

    Me.dataGridView1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill

    Me.reloadButton.Text = "reload"
    Me.submitButton.Text = "submit"

    Dim panel As New FlowLayoutPanel()
    panel.Dock = DockStyle.Top
    panel.AutoSize = True
    panel.Controls.AddRange(New Control() {Me.reloadButton, Me.submitButton})

    Me.Controls.AddRange(New Control() {Me.dataGridView1, panel})
    Me.Text = "DataGridView databinding and updating demo"

End Sub

Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
    Handles Me.Load

    //' Bind the DataGridView to the BindingSource
    //' and load the data from the database.
    Me.dataGridView1.DataSource = Me.bindingSource1
    GetData(strSelect)

End Sub

Private Sub reloadButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
    Handles reloadButton.Click

    //' Reload the data from the database.
    GetData(Me.dataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandText)

End Sub

Private Sub submitButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
    Handles submitButton.Click

    //' Update the database with the user's changes.
    Me.dataAdapter.Update(CType(Me.bindingSource1.DataSource, DataTable))

End Sub

Private Sub GetData(ByVal selectCommand As String)

    Try

        Me.dataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter(selectCommand, connectionString)

        Dim commandBuilder As New MYSqlCommandBuilder(Me.dataAdapter)

        Dim MyDataTable As New DataTable()

        MyDataTable.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
        Me.dataAdapter.Fill(MyDataTable)
        Me.bindingSource1.DataSource = MyDataTable

        //' Resize the DataGridView columns to fit the newly loaded content.
        Me.dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns( _
            DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCellsExceptHeader)
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try

End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Cannot duplicate. I have a trigger that logs the DateTime of the last change to a table and it runs fine with a `DataAdapter` (the DB doesnt know what you are using in code). It might be a problem with the trigger.  You should also get rid of the empty `Catch` so you at least know when something goes wrong.

Comment: thx for quick reply !

Comment: Catch is empty only for this eample code here ;) And yes, as it was my opinion, the DB doesn't know anything of my code and should always run if record is changed. But: If I edit field No 2 in MS ACCESS as frontend, the easy trigger runs fine ( CREATE TRIGGER `mydb`.`tri_person_afterupdate` 
 BEFORE UPDATE ON `tbl_person`
        FOR EACH ROW SET new.Updated = NOW(); ) But if I use the above code, it doesn't run. And I have really no idea why.

Comment: Your supose with the issue in the trigger was right. I renewed the trigger and it works fine now.